# Relentless message "macOS Updates Installed" ever since last OS update

Tags: macos, software-update, notifications

Since my last OS update after every restart the following message pops up:

> macOS Updates Installed.
>   Your computer restarted to install these updates.

[image: macOS Updates Installed popup]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: ask the second question as a separate question

Comment: What happens when you click the 'Details' button?

Comment: @IconDaemon: I've just restarted my computer in order to answer your question, and guess what? The message did not pop up! Maybe it's fixed itself spontaneously. I hope it's not a fluke.